# Using Boost adaptors with C++11 lambdas

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, c++11, boost-range

I tried to compile this code:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{
        1,5,4,2,8,5,3,7,9
    };
    std::cout << *boost::min_element(v | boost::adaptors::transformed(
            [](int i) { return -i; })) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The compilation failed with the following error message (after a long template instantiation novel):

```
/usr/local/include/boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp:84:26: error: use of deleted function ‘main()::<lambda(int)>::<lambda>()’
../main.cpp:12:5: error: a lambda closure type has a deleted default constructor
```

I googled the problem, and found [this](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Compilation-errors-when-trying-to-use-range-adaptors-with-C-11-lambdas-td4631527.html) in the Boost Users mailing list archive. It suggested that using `#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE` would solve the problem. I put it into the very beginning of my code, but it still doesn't compile. The length of the error message seems to be much shorter, but the error message at the end is the same. I'm currently using Boost 1.50.

What can be the problem here? Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: I think you need 1.51. At least that is what made it work for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2011/10/31/linq-to-c-or-something-much-better/

But you can use this, that works well.

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{
        1,5,4,2,8,5,3,7,9
    };
    std::function<int(int)> func = [](int i) { return -i; };
    std::cout << *boost::min_element(v | boost::adaptors::transformed(
    func)) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

http://liveworkspace.org/code/b78b3f7d05049515ac207e0c12054c70

`#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE` works fine in VS2012 for example.

Comment: `std::function` works with type erasure, i.e., with a virtual function. This additional cost is unnecessary here and probably unacceptable. (also inlining is hindered) My solution would be using `std::ref`.

Answer (score 11):

You can turn a non-capturing lambda into a function pointer by putting a "+" in front of it.

```
std::vector<int> v{1,5,4,2,8,5,3,7,9};
std::cout << *boost::min_element(v | 
    boost::adaptors::transformed(+[](int i) 
    {
        return -i; 
    })) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 6):

This is covered at http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/range-cannot-use-lambda-predicate-in-adaptor-with-certain-algorithms-td3560157.html and https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4189 - the problem is that some algorithms expect to be able to copy-construct (and default-construct, and copy-assign) their predicate, which can't be done with a lambda.

The workaround is to wrap the lambda in a `std::function`:

```
*boost::min_element(
    v | boost::adaptors::transformed(std::function<int(int)>(
        [](int i) { return -i; })));
```

I've asked (at [Inferring the call signature of a lambda or arbitrary callable for "make_function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893141/inferring-the-call-signature-of-a-lambda-or-arbitrary-callable-for-make-functio)) for a way to write a `make_function` such that one can just write:

```
*boost::min_element(
    v | boost::adaptors::transformed(make_function(
        [](int i) { return -i; })));
```

Answer (score 0):

With C++17 feature [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) you can wrap with std::function simplier, like this:

```
*boost::min_element(
    v | boost::adaptors::transformed(std::function(
        [](int i) { return -i; })));
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, the problem is, that `std::min_element()` (which is simply wrapped by `boost::min_element()`) wants to copy the begin iterator of the range. But this iterator contains an instance of the transforming callable (same thing happens with a filtering callable) which therefore must be copied as well. But lambdas are not copyable so this will not compile.

It was suggested to wrap the lambda in a `std::function`, but this has the downside of a virtual function call with every invocation. Virtual function calls are not for free and you'll have to pay that cost for every element in your range. (virtual functions also hinder inlining)

The better solution is to use [`std::cref()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) so that the iterator contains a `std::reference_wrapper` which is basically a pointer:

```
static constexpr auto transformer = [](int i) { return -i; };
std::cout << *boost::min_element(v | boost::adaptors::transformed(std::cref(transformer))) << std::endl;
```

See it working on [Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/473fe6dc5d59c2c1).

This also works for capturing lambdas, however those cannot be `static constexpr`.