# Inferring the call signature of a lambda or arbitrary callable for "make_function"

Tags: c++, function, lambda, c++11, type-inference

In some situations it's desirable to be able to type-erase a callable (e.g. function, function pointer, object instance with `operator()`, lambda, `mem_fn`), for instance in [Using Boost adaptors with C++11 lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872558/using-boost-adaptors-with-c11-lambdas) where a copy-assignable and default-constructible type is required.

`std::function` would be ideal, but there seems to be no way to *automatically* determine what signature to instantiate the class template `std::function` with.  Is there an easy way to get the function signature of an arbitrary callable and/or wrap it in an appropriate `std::function` instantiation instance (i.e. a `make_function` function template)?

Specifically, I'm looking for one or other of

```
template<typename F> using get_signature = ...;
template<typename F> std::function<get_signature<F>> make_function(F &&f) { ... }
```

such that `make_function([](int i) { return 0; })` returns a `std::function<int(int)>`.  Obviously this wouldn't be expected to work if an instance is callable with more than one signature (e.g. objects with more than one, template or default-parameter `operator()`s).

Boost is fine, although non-Boost solutions that aren't excessively complex are preferred.

---

Edit: answering my own question.

Comment: If you only care for lambdas then yes, you can get it to work. I'd advise against that -- I suspect that introspecting functors is somewhat of an antipattern in C++11. Make also sure that you really need `std::function`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I've come up with a fairly nasty non-library solution, using the fact that lambdas have `operator()`:

```
template<typename T> struct remove_class { };
template<typename C, typename R, typename... A>
struct remove_class<R(C::*)(A...)> { using type = R(A...); };
template<typename C, typename R, typename... A>
struct remove_class<R(C::*)(A...) const> { using type = R(A...); };
template<typename C, typename R, typename... A>
struct remove_class<R(C::*)(A...) volatile> { using type = R(A...); };
template<typename C, typename R, typename... A>
struct remove_class<R(C::*)(A...) const volatile> { using type = R(A...); };

template<typename T>
struct get_signature_impl { using type = typename remove_class<
    decltype(&std::remove_reference<T>::type::operator())>::type; };
template<typename R, typename... A>
struct get_signature_impl<R(A...)> { using type = R(A...); };
template<typename R, typename... A>
struct get_signature_impl<R(&)(A...)> { using type = R(A...); };
template<typename R, typename... A>
struct get_signature_impl<R(*)(A...)> { using type = R(A...); };
template<typename T> using get_signature = typename get_signature_impl<T>::type;

template<typename F> using make_function_type = std::function<get_signature<F>>;
template<typename F> make_function_type<F> make_function(F &&f) {
    return make_function_type<F>(std::forward<F>(f)); }
```

Any ideas where this can be simplified or improved? Any obvious bugs?

Comment: +1.  
What  `get_signature_impl` bool template parameter does?

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky it's completely unnecessary; I've removed it.  I think I put it in there when I was writing `get_signature` as a recursive template but it's not needed now.

Comment: why put & in decltype(&std::remove_reference<T>::type::operator())>::type ?

Comment: @ecatmur: no sorry it seems it is mandatory at least under g++4.8 I'm just wondering why

Comment: Ah, my mistake.  The `&` is mandatory; per 5.1.1p13 the expression inside `decltype` is an id-expression denoting a non-static member function, so can only be used to form a pointer-to-member.  There's no such thing as a member function type, only a pointer to member function type.

Comment: FWIW, with generic lambdas this will no longer work.

Comment: It doesn't work in the obvious cases where the signature is ambiguous (e.g. polymorphic lambdas, template `operator()` or more overloads for `operator()`). It also doesn't work if your class is not copyable but movable, even if you pass it as a temporary. It seems to be a problem with `std::function` though.

Comment: Incredible. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Impossible. You may be able to take the address of `operator()` for *some* types, but not for an arbitrary callable, because it may well have overloads or template parameters. Whether or not it would work for a lambda is most assuredly not well-defined, AFAIK.

Comment: Good point, but I'm primarily concerned with lambdas, where exactly one `operator()` exists.

Comment: Well, it's certainly not well-defined that that is the case, and I'm not actually sure that it's even defined that one exists.

Comment: 5.1.2:5 *The closure type for a lambda-expression has a public inline function call operator [...]*

Answer (score 1):

For non-variadic non-generic captureless lambda functions as well as simple free functions one can use following approach:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cstdlib>

template< typename L, typename R, typename ...A >
constexpr
auto // std::function< R (A...) >
to_function_pointer(L l, R (L::*)(A...) const)
{
    return static_cast< R (*)(A...) >(l);
}

template< typename L, typename R, typename ...A >
constexpr
auto // std::function< R (A...) >
to_function_pointer(L l, R (L::*)(A...)) // for mutable lambda
{
    return static_cast< R (*)(A...) >(l);
}

template< typename L >
constexpr
auto
to_function_pointer(L l)
{
    return to_function_pointer(l, &L::operator ());
}

template< typename R, typename ...A >
constexpr
auto // std::function< R (A...) >
to_function_pointer(R (* fp)(A...))
{
    return fp;
}

namespace
{

void f() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

}

int
main()
{
    to_function_pointer([] () { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; })();
    //to_function_pointer([&] () { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; })(); // can't cast from non-captureless lambda to function pointer
    to_function_pointer([] () mutable { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; })();
    to_function_pointer(f)();
    to_function_pointer(&f)();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```