# Metastructures vs metafunctions

Tags: c++

Why do we still use structures and `typedef`s (or `using`s) for metaprogramming?

Look at the code in this question - [Inferring the call signature of a lambda or arbitrary callable for "make_function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893141/inferring-the-call-signature-of-a-lambda-or-arbitrary-callable-for-make-functio) :

```
template<typename T> struct remove_class { };
template<typename C, typename R, typename... A>
struct remove_class<R(C::*)(A...)> { using type = R(A...); };

template<typename T, bool> struct get_signature_impl { };
template<typename R, typename... A>
struct get_signature_impl<R(A...), true> { using type = R(A...); };
template<typename R, typename... A>
struct get_signature_impl<R(*)(A...), true> { using type = R(A...); };
template<typename T>
struct get_signature_impl<T, true> { using type = typename remove_class<
    decltype(&std::remove_reference<T>::type::operator())>::type; };
```

There is a lot of weird tricks like that `bool`, noisy keywords like `typename`, redundant stuff like `struct get_signature_impl;`.
It's great that we got the `using` keyword in C++11, but it doesn't make much difference.

In C++11 we have `decltype` and trailing-return-type. With this power, we can drop all the ugly *metastructures*, and write beautiful *metafunctions*.
So, we can rewrite the code above:

```
template<typename C, typename R, typename... A> auto make_function_aux(R(C::*)(A...)) -> std::function<R(A...)>;
template<typename C, typename R, typename... A> auto make_function_aux(R(C::*)(A...) const) -> std::function<R(A...)>;
template<typename R, typename... A> auto make_function_aux(R(A...)) -> std::function<R(A...)>;
template<typename R, typename... A> auto make_function_aux(R(*)(A...)) -> std::function<R(A...)>;
template<typename T> auto make_function_aux(const T&) -> decltype(make_function_aux(&T::operator()));

template<typename F> auto make_function(F&& f) -> decltype(make_function_aux(f)) { return decltype(make_function_aux(f))(std::forward<F>(f)); }
```

Are there any situations where template partial specialisation is better than function overloading with `decltype` for matching template arguments, or is this just a case of programmer inertia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of a few issues with using function overloading:

Different matching rules; a list of template specialisations will only match exactly, while function overloads will match if the arguments are convertible to the parameter types.  This can usually be worked around, but it could lead to more complicated metacode in some cases.

Restriction on return types; functions can't return some types e.g. functions (not function pointers), abstract classes, noncopyable types (I think), arrays-of-unknown-bound (possibly).  This can be worked around by encapsulating the type in a template struct.

In general you're likely to see a tradeoff between on one side the use of `typename` and `using`, and on the other side the use of `decltype` and wrapper templates.

I'd agree though that your above code is an improvement on the original, for the elimination of the `bool` trick alone.