# c++ I need to store in a structure the "type" of an object among various classes with inheritance and virtual functions

Tags: c++

I use g++.

I have a hierarchy of classes that inherith each from previous ones.

There are two versions of the same classes, one version is a Plain Old Data POD simple struct, the other version contains virtual functions.

I have seen there is the typeid, so I save it somehow with the POD structure.

I need now to convert the POD data using the saved typeid and have the polymorphic class.

How do I do it ?

Some sample code is:

```
#include <iostream>    // cout
#include <typeinfo>  //for 'typeid'

struct Person0{
    int weight;
};

struct Employee0:Person0{
    double salary;
};

struct Person: Person0 {
public:
   // ... Person members ...
   virtual ~Person() {}
};

struct Employee:Employee0,Person {
   // ... Employee members ...
};

int main() 
{
   Person person;
   Employee employee;

     void *p1=&person;      const std::type_info* p1t=&typeid(person);
     void *p2=&employee;    const std::type_info* p2t=&typeid(employee);

// now I need to get back to person using only p1 and p1t 
// and to employee 

     Person personCopy = *some_casting<*p1t>(p1);
     Employee employeeCopy = *some_casting<*p2t>(p2);

}
```

Comment: Completely unclear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Errr...usually if you need to do this you've screwed up your design.

Comment: Are your classes polymorphic (i.e. have at least one virtual function or base)? In that case, there's no need to save the typeid separately, just use `dynamic_cast` or `typeid`. Maybe interesting: [“type-switch” construct in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822836/type-switch-construct-in-c11)

Comment: @deduplicator Yes classes are polymorfic, but I will use a POD version of them. So I want to convert a pointer to the POD version to an appropriate pointer using the saved typeid&.

Comment: You should thoroughly ask your design if [`is a`](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/polymorphism/intro/) really applies! _'Yes classes are polymorphic, but I will use a POD version of them.'_ sounds pretty confused for me.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis: This code is a good start, but missing a key piece.  Namely, why do you need to "get back to the most derived type?"  If it's because a function needs to work with an employee, then simply do a `dynamic_cast`.  If it's because you need to dispatch based on the type, then use a virtual function, or one of the bits of code from my answer.  I don't think there are any other situations in real code.

Comment: I save in memory a POD version of the struct. That struct contains a propietary field containing a "type". That internal "type" is used as an inded to a table containing whatever I need, including the typeid of the data. I need to apply that typeid to the POD data to use the virtual functions of the related class.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis: Also, there's no POD in your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Either iterate over the types with dynamic_cast

```
 interface* base_ptr = ????;

 if(dynamic_cast<derived1*>(base_ptr))
     do_task_with_derived_1(dynamic_cast<derived1*>(base_ptr));
 if(dynamic_cast<derived2*>(base_ptr))
     do_task_with_derived_2(dynamic_cast<derived2*>(base_ptr));
 if(dynamic_cast<derived3*>(base_ptr))
     do_task_with_derived_3(dynamic_cast<derived3*>(base_ptr));
 //etc etc etc
```

Or form a lookup table of type_id to functions. (or better yet, make the function a virtual member)

```
static const std::unordered_map<std::type_id, std::function<void(interface*)> dispatcher =
    {
        {typeid(derived1), [](interface* p){
           do_task_with_derived_1(dynamic_cast<derived1*>(base_ptr);} },
        {typeid(derived2), [](interface* p){
           do_task_with_derived_2(dynamic_cast<derived2*>(base_ptr);} },
        {typeid(derived3), [](interface* p){
           do_task_with_derived_3(dynamic_cast<derived3*>(base_ptr);} },
    };

interface* base_ptr = ???;
dispatcher[typeid(*base_ptr)](base_ptr);
```

Comment: There should be a way to have a pointer to Plain Old Data and a typeid of what we would like to have and cast that to what we need.

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis: I no longer have any idea what you're trying to say, sorry :(  After editing your question that there's now two types of each class, I'm thoroughly confused.  However, whatever you're doing, these are the two normal ways of doing dynamic dispatch for non-member functions.  Maybe if you gave a few samples?