# Deduce std::function parameters from lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm trying to accept multiple arguments in a `std::function`, but I got [errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbc3384a255c4d5f):

```
#include <functional>

template <typename... Args>
void caller(std::function<void(Args&&...)> function)
{

}

int main()
{
    caller([&] () { });
}
```

The error is:

```
main.cpp:11:22: error: no matching function for call to 'caller(main()::<lambda()>)'
     caller([&] () { });
                      ^
main.cpp:11:22: note: candidate is:
main.cpp:4:6: note: template<class ... Args> void caller(std::function<void(Args&& ...)>)
 void caller(std::function<void(Args&&...)> function)
      ^
main.cpp:4:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:11:22: note:   'main()::<lambda()>' is not derived from 'std::function<void(Args&& ...)>'
     caller([&] () { });
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Hello! Please provide a complete example and specify what exact error you are getting.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358672/how-to-convert-a-lambda-to-an-stdfunction-using-templates

Answer (score -2):

Maybe

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename F>
void caller(std::function<F> function)
{

}

void f() {
    caller<void()>([&] () {
        std::cout << "Hi." << std::endl;
    });
}
```

or even

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename F>
void caller(F function)
{

}

void f() {
    caller<void()>([&] () {
        std::cout << "Hi." << std::endl;
    });
}
```

Both codes do compile, but I don't know how can they be useful to youm, if I don't know what you to do...