# C++ 11 async programming using template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda, std-function

I'm writing a class to achieve task feature.
Here is my code:

```
template<typename TType>
class YHMTask
{
public:
    YHMTask() {};
    std::future<TType> mTask;
};

template<typename T>
YHMTask<T> YHMCreateTask(std::function<T()> func)
{
    YHMTask<T> yhmTask;
    yhmTask.mTask = std::async(func);
    return yhmTask;
}
```

If I didn't use template  in YHMCreateTask, I can use it like this:

```
YHMCreateTask([]{return 12;});
```

But when I writing this function using template.
Compiler report this error:

```
error C2672: 'YHMCreateTask': no matching overloaded function found
error C2784: 'YHMTask<TType> YHMCreateTask(std::function<_Type(void)>)': could not deduce template argument for 'std::function<_Type(void)>' from 'main::<lambda_a66b482c6cd6dab7208879904592bde5>'
```

I have to use YHMCreateTask like this:

```
int TestFunc()
{
    return 11;
}
...
std::function<int(void)> funInt = TestFunc;
auto taskNew = YHMCreateTask(funInt);
```

I want YHMCreateTask can be used like YHMCreateTask([]{return 12;});
How should I do?

Comment: Related to [how-to-convert-a-lambda-to-an-stdfunction-using-templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358672/how-to-convert-a-lambda-to-an-stdfunction-using-templates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use something like:

```
template<typename F>
auto YHMCreateTask(F func)
-> YHMTask<decltype(func())>
{
    YHMTask<decltype(func())> yhmTask;
    yhmTask.mTask = std::async(func);
    return yhmTask;
}
```

`T` cannot be deduced from lamdba to construct `std::function`