# Function pointer overloading using typedef

Tags: c++

As I understand, `typedef` cannot be used for overloading but what if I need to use some different types as arguments to the function pointer?
How can I make it work with the following functionality?

```
{
public:
    typedef void (*InitFunc)(float x);  
    typedef void (*InitFunc)(int a, char b);   //Needs to be added
    virtual void initialize(InitFunc init) = 0;
};
```

**Edit:**
I cannot use C++17, so can't use `variant`

Comment: Can't you make two different typedefs (with different names), and two overloads for `initialize`?

Comment: Are you asking how to accept different functions as an argument?

Comment: I don't know the C++ equivalent, but one method is to use something like `Either<FuncType1, FuncType2>`. But since it's C++, maybe there's some template magic?

Comment: Would really like to know the exact requirement. Why do you need this thing?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - cannot.

Comment: @KunalPuri I have two chips my microcontroller talks with and one of them has an additional feature. I've reduced the complexity of the module with the simple example above

Comment: Then why can't you go for @HolyBlackCat's approach?

Comment: @KunalPuri the derived classes expand the class above and use the same type (```InitFunc```). I cannot change them easily

Comment: @Ronen333 the easiest, hacky way would be a union

Comment: `Either<FuncType1, FuncType2>` would be `std::variant<FuncType1, FuncType2>`

Answer (score 0):

As commented, the easiest way is a union, although not very type safe and C++-y. Here is an example with inheritance, since you commented that you want inheritance.

```
typedef void (*FloatInit)(float x);  
typedef void (*IntCharInit)(int a, char b); 

union InitFn {
    FloatInit fi;
    IntCharInit ici;
};

struct Foo {
    void initialize(InitFn) = 0;
};

struct FloatFoo: public Foo {
    void initialize(InitFn f) override {
        f.fi(42.0f);
    }
};

void test(float) {}

// ...
auto x = FloatFoo{};
x.initialize(InitFn{test});
```

As mentioned by other commenters, you can use `std::variant` to enhance type safety and get rid of the manual union definition:

```
typedef void (*FloatInit)(float x);  
typedef void (*IntCharInit)(int a, char b); 

typedef std::variant<FloatInit, IntCharInit> InitFn;

struct Foo {
    void initialize(InitFn) = 0;
};

struct FloatFoo: public Foo {
    void initialize(InitFn f) override {
        std::get<FloatInit>(f)(42.0f);
    }
};

void test(float) {}

// ...
auto x = FloatFoo{};
x.initialize(InitFn{test});
```

Comment: I cannot use C++17 (so can't use ```variant```) and the ```union``` needs to use its internal member's names (```fi``` at your example)

Comment: @Ronen333 then define a struct that encapsulates the union and offers an operator()

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a simple wrapper class template instead, to allow the compiler to automatically generate instantiations as necessary.  This is relatively simple if `init` is always guaranteed to be a non-member function (and by extension, an actual function and not a functor/lambda).

```
// Quick-and-dirty transparent callable wrapper, to serve as overloadable "type alias".
template<typename>
class InitFunc;

template<typename Ret, typename... Params>
class InitFunc<Ret(*)(Params...)> {
  public:
    // Supply component types if needed.
    // Tuple used for params, for convenience.
    using   return_type = Ret;
    using   param_types = std::tuple<Params...>;
    using     func_type = Ret(Params...);
    using func_ptr_type = func_type*;
    using func_ref_type = func_type&;

    // Create from pointer or reference.
    constexpr InitFunc(func_ptr_type p = nullptr) : ptr(p) {}
    constexpr InitFunc(func_ref_type r) : ptr(&r) {}

    // Transparent invocation.
    // Deduces argument types instead of relying on Params, to allow for perfect forwarding.
    template<typename... Ts>
    constexpr return_type operator()(Ts&&... ts) { return ptr(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...); }

    // Convert back to original type if necessary.
    operator func_ptr_type() { return ptr; }
    operator func_ref_type() { return *ptr; }

  private:
    // Actual function pointer.
    func_ptr_type ptr;
};

// And a nice, clean creator, which can be renamed as necessary.
template<typename Init>
constexpr auto make(Init func) { return InitFunc<Init>(func); }
```

This creates a nice little wrapper that can easily be optimised out entirely, and [will compile as long as C++14 support is available](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/212e320ddf5d8629).

<sup>Note that you require a C++11 compiler (or variadic templates, rvalue references, perfect forwarding, and `constexpr` support) at the absolute minimum, and will need to modify `make()` to have a trailing return type for pre-C++14 compilers.  I *believe* this is compatible with C++11 `constexpr`, but I'm not 100% sure.</sup>

---

If you want `InitFunc` to be able to accept pointers/references-to-member-function (including functors and lambdas), you'll need to provide an additional version to isolate it into a non-member "function", and likely bind it to a class instance.  It may be worth looking into `std::bind()` in this case, although I'm not sure if it has any overhead.

In this case, I would suggest splitting the member types off into a base class, to reduce the amount of code you'll need to duplicate.

```
// Quick-and-dirty transparent callable wrapper, to serve as overloadable "type alias".
template<typename>
class InitFunc;

// Supply component types if needed.
// Tuple used for params, for convenience.
// Using actual function type as a base, similar to std::function.
template<typename Ret, typename... Params>
class InitFunc<Ret(Params...)> {
  public:
    using   return_type = Ret;
    using   param_types = std::tuple<Params...>;
    using     func_type = Ret(Params...);
    using func_ptr_type = func_type*;
    using func_ref_type = func_type&;
};

// Non-member functions.
// As member types are now dependent types, we qualify them and use `typename`.
//  Yes, it looks just as silly as you think it does.
template<typename Ret, typename... Params>
class InitFunc<Ret(*)(Params...)> : public InitFunc<Ret(Params...)> {
    // Actual function pointer.
    typename InitFunc::func_ptr_type ptr;

  public:
    // Create from pointer or reference.
    constexpr InitFunc(typename InitFunc::func_ptr_type p = nullptr) : ptr(p) {}
    constexpr InitFunc(typename InitFunc::func_ref_type r) : ptr(&r) {}

    // Transparent invocation.
    // Deduces argument types instead of relying on Params, to allow for perfect forwarding.
    template<typename... Ts>
    constexpr typename InitFunc::return_type operator()(Ts&&... ts) { return ptr(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...); }

    // Convert back to original type if necessary.
    operator typename InitFunc::func_ptr_type() { return ptr; }
    operator typename InitFunc::func_ref_type() { return *ptr; }
};

// See ecatmur's http://stackoverflow.com/a/13359520/5386374 for how to accomodate member functions.
// ...

// Non-member function make() is unaffected.
// An overload will likely be needed for member functions.
template<typename Init>
auto make(Init func) { return InitFunc<Init>(func); }
```

Despite the awkwardness inside our derived specialisation, any code that relies on `InitFunc` shouldn't (to my knowledge) see any changes to its API; the previous example will [work just fine if we swap to this new `InitFunc`](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db974178df621b22), and be none the wiser after recompilation.

<sup>Note that it will change the ABI, though, and thus any code compiled for the simpler `InitFunc` will need to be recompiled for this version.</sup>