# Optimization of code behind heavy templating

Tags: c++, templates

I have been using only basic C++ (STL containers, simple templating) in the past few years. Now I finally decided to learn some more advanced(?) templating by implementing pattern matching on `std::variant` with the goal of being easy to use and possible to optimize well.

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>
#include <string>

namespace Match {

namespace Make_fun {

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358672/how-to-convert-a-lambda-to-an-stdfunction-using-templates
template <typename T>
struct memfun_type {
    using type = void;
};

template <typename Ret, typename Class, typename... Args>
struct memfun_type<Ret(Class::*)(Args...) const> {
    using type = std::function<Ret(Args...)>;
};

// Function from lambda !
template <typename F>
typename memfun_type<decltype(&F::operator())>::type
make_fun(F const &func) { 
    return func;
}

} // Make_fun

template <typename R, typename T>
struct MatchBranch {
    using type = T;
    std::function<R(T)> f;
    MatchBranch<R, T> (std::function<R(T)> f) : f(f) {}
};

template <typename F>
auto operator!(F f) {
    return MatchBranch(Make_fun::make_fun(f));
}

template<typename ...Args>
struct variant_from_branches {
    using type = std::variant<std::remove_reference_t<typename Args::type>...>;
};

template <typename R, typename T, typename... Args>
R match(T&& variant, Args&&... branches) {
    return match<R>(
        std::forward<T>(variant),
        std::forward<Args...>(branches...));
}

template <typename R, typename T, typename B, typename... Args>
R match(T&& variant, B&& branch, Args&&... branches) {
    static_assert(
        std::is_same_v<
            typename std::remove_reference<T>::type,
            typename variant_from_branches<B, Args...>::type>,
        "Branch types does not match variant type. "
        "Branches must be exhaustive and must follow the order of type "
        "appearance in std::variant<...> declaration");

    if (std::holds_alternative<typename B::type>(variant)) {
        return branch.f(std::get<typename B::type>(variant));
    }
    return match<R>(
        std::forward<T>(variant),
        std::forward<Args...>(branches...));
}

template <typename R, typename T, typename B>
R match(T&& variant, B&& branch) {
    // should always match
    return branch.f(std::get<typename B::type>(variant));
}


} // Match
```

Example usage:

```cpp
int main() {
    using namespace Match;
    std::variant<int, const char*> v = "abc";
    return match<int>(
        v,
        ![](int a) { return a; },
        ![](const char* s) { return s[0]; }
        );
}
```

This code can optimize well (clang optimizing `main()` to a single `return 'a';`. But when `const char*` is changed to `std::string`, clang gives me a bunch of code that I don't understand.

```cpp
int main() {
    using namespace Match;
    std::variant<int, std::string> v = "abc";
    return match<int>(
        v,
        ![](int a) { return a; },
        ![](std::string s) { return s[0]; }
        );
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5f7voMTen)

I expected clang to optimize the above code to a single `return 'a';` because it could do it if I write

```cpp
int main() {
    return std::string("abc")[0];
}
```

Did the heavy templating prevent clang from optimizing the code? Is there any way to optimize my template code?

Comment: Doesn't help with the problem but since C++17 your `make_fun` function can be simplified to `template <typename F> auto make_fun(const F& f) { return std::function{f}; }` to take advantage of CTAD (class template argument deduction)

Comment: I don't know the answer to your specific question. I'd just like to note that you seem to be reinventing [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit)

Comment: `std::function` is very opaque to most optimizers. You could try to use template types instead, that might help the compiler to optimize the program. Also an unconstrained template `operator!` declaration seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Probably I am reinventing `std::visit`. But this is actually an exercise for me to learn and practice templating.

Comment: `std::variant<int, const char*>` can almost be as simple as `union foo { int, const char *};` and all of it operations are trivial.  `std::variant<int, std::string>` cannot be so simple as `string` is non-trival so all parts of the union must get defined (ctor, copy, destructor, ..)

Comment: `return std::get<std::string>(std::variant<std::string, int>("abc"))[0];` does optimize to `return 'a'`...

Comment: For the record, [your example rewritten with `std::visit`](https://godbolt.org/z/habad3E4v) optimizes down to `mov eax, 97; ret` I concur that the problem is likely `std::function`, and you should avoid wrapping your callbacks into it.

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/P9E73f398) is a simplified version of your code (that also basically reimplements `std::visit`) that does not use `std::function` and optimizes to `mov eax, 97`

Comment: I guess I have to spend some time studying your simplified version @chrysante

Comment: @Austin Sorry, I guess I could have done a better job at commenting that, give me a minute

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/9E865T5vv I hope this helps :)

Comment: OMG thank you so much this is so inspirational. I always thought recursion is the only way to iterate through parameter pack. I saw creating a struct that inherits from type parameter pack from [the example in `std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) but I never really understand it (should have googled it but I thought it is too advanced for now). @chrysante

Comment: Yes since C++17 with fold expressions it is much easier to work with variadic templates. I'm glad it helped :)