# std::array and lambda

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

```
#include <array>
#include <functional>

template<typename T, typename ... Args>
auto make_array(T&& t, Args&& ... args) -> std::array<T, sizeof...(Args)+1> {
    return {std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}

int main() {
    auto f = [](int i)->int { return i; };
    auto f2 = [](int i)->int { return i*2; };

    auto arr2 = make_array<std::function<int(int)>>(f, f2);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to not specify the template type at call site `make_array<std::function<int(int)>>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to let the parameter type be deduced. With [this clever solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12283159/1932150) by [ecatmur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/567292/ecatmur) you can automatically generate the proper `std::function<>` object:

```
template<typename T, typename ... Args>
auto make_array(T&& t, Args&& ... args) -> 
    std::array<make_function_type<T>, sizeof...(Args)+1>
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    return {std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}

#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    auto f = [](int i)->int { return i; };
    auto f2 = [](int i)->int { return i*2; };

    auto arr2 = make_array(f, f2);
    std::cout << arr2[1](21); // Prints 42

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/14AM9l$6).