# Can I use std::function (C++11 lambda) with Boost?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Boost adaptors with C++11 lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872558/using-boost-adaptors-with-c11-lambdas)

I would like to use Boost range adaptors to map (transform) a map to a list, through a C++11 lambda function.
Like this:

```
  boost::copy(myMap | transformed([](pair<string, string> p){return p.first;}),
              ostream_iterator<string>(cout, ", "));
```

This won't work, because std::function does not have a value_type-type. I know that this particular transformation can be done with map_keys, but my point is more general. How can I use C++11 lambdas with Boost?

If it cannot be done without boilerplate, are there any plans to fix this issue? I have tried searching for it, but found suprisingly little.

Comment: Note: C++11 lambdas and `std::function` are *two different things.* Your code doesn't use `std::function` at all.

Comment: I thought that C++11 lambdas were compatible with std::function and, as such, are in some sense std::functions.

Answer (score 1):

I found it myself! Starting with Boost 1.51.0, you add

```
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
```

Before including the boost files, and it will magically use decltype instead of ::value_type to infer return type. Now my example works!

Comment: Tread carefully now. This macro is a lot older than Boost 1.51 and has a tendency to cause trouble with older Boost Versions due to a number of problems.

Comment: I require 1.51 in my CMake-file. Is that enough, or are there still trouble ahead? Do you have a reference?

Comment: There is this huge thread on boost.devel http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel/233752/focus=234254 It boils down to a bug in decltype spec that got fixed late in the standardization, lots of compilers not conforming to the newest spec and many problems in boost where some specific behavior of `decltype/result_of` was assumed. You should be fine with Boost 1.51 and a completely compliant compiler.